# The meaning of "Mas quá!"

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

In the song "Todo Menino é um Rei" ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHv-m7YlSqc)) we have the following passage:

> Todo menino é um rei
>
> Eu também já fui rei
>
> Mas quá!
>
> Despertei!

My doubt is: What's the meaning of "Mas quá!"?
I didn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olhando no [Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/qu%C3%A1/), "quá" é uma expressão regionalística que denota dúvida.

Exemplo:

> Quá... Isso não vai dar em nada

Outra fonte que não sei até onde pode ser usada como uma boa referência, mas a desciclopédia tem uma página com um [dicionário e verbetes Goianeses](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Goian%C3%AAs) (Goiás é um estado brasileiro), que cita um exemplo parecido:

> **Ou quá?** - Algo como “ou o quê?”. Ex.: “Você vai sair com a gente ou quá?”

Uma fonte bem mais embasada: um [trabalho de conclusão de mestrado](http://www.ufmt.br/ufmt/unidade/userfiles/publicacoes/51cf001d9a7d6e3854b6883561abf068.pdf) da Universidade Federal de Mato Grosso, pág. 112, que apesar de não explicar seu significado tem um trecho interessante onde afirma que o "quá" tem origem típica dos africanos escravos que residiam em Mato Grosso (outro estado brasileiro).

Em dois outros artigos que encontrei que possuem o termo "quá" em seu corpo, que apesar de também não explicarem seu significado dão mais dicas de como utilizá-lo em uma frase.

Um deles é essa [Tese ao Programa de Pós-Graduação em Letras](http://www.lume.ufrgs.br/bitstream/handle/10183/28002/000766991.pdf?...1), pela Universidade do Rio Grande do Sul, pág. 35:

> – Quá [...] era nele que você ia votar? Foi nele que se votou das outras feitas? Inimigos todos semos; mas, chega o dia, encilho o baio e marcho. Faço assim!

E nesse outro [Artigo sobre o uso das variantes regionalistas na poesia de Catulo da Paixão Cearense](http://www.linguagemidentidades.ufma.br/publicacoes/pdf/Artigo%20Jose%20Ribamar%20Neres%20Costa.pdf), pág. 8:

> Cantei tanto essa tuada
>   que o coração m doêu!
>   Mas porêm... quá, meu patrão!
>   Era Pedro Cumaé
>   o rêis do seu coração

Comment: Excelente pesquisa. Então *quá* é ou foi usado do Rio Grande do Sul ao Maranhão!

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigado :) Eu não tenho tanta certeza de que ele foi usado no Rio Grande do Sul também, teria que ler o trabalho com mais atenção para se certificar e de repente fazer mais algumas pesquisas, mas ao que parece foi sim.

Comment: Parece-me que foi. Quem diz "quá [...] era nele que você ia votar?" é Chico Pedro, descrito na página anterior como um gaúcho típico.

Comment: @Jacinto tem toda razão! Viajando um pouco agora... será que o "quá" deu origem ao "bá" dos gaúchos?

Comment: "bá" é usado da mesma maneira que "quá"?

Comment: @Jacinto pensando bem, não muito. É mais para demonstrar espanto. De acordo com o dicionário informal ele é abreviação de "barbaridade": http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/b%C3%A1/6740/ Falei que era só uma viagem, rs

Answer (score 3):

Ouvi a música há algumas décadas e, na ocasião, achei tratar-se de "Mas Qual !"    Mas vejo que a letra da música em vários sites cita "Quá".  Contudo, não existe "quá" em ptBR, e nem consta no meu Aurélio.  Embora a música seja brasileira, acredito que o autor tenha querido dizer "Mas qual !" que encaixa perfeitamente no contexto.   É a única explicação que vejo.

Edit: **"qual"** [**é uma interjeição usada para exprimir dúvida, incredulidade ou negação**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/qual). "Mas qual!' e "Qual o quê!" são variações e têm o mesmo significado.

Comment: Acho que é aquele sotaque brasileiro de dizer "r" em vez de "l". "Mas quar", faz sentido assim?

Comment: Esta resposta seria melhorada se explicasse como o significado apontado encaixa na estória contada pelos outros versos.

Comment: @ANeves   Pensei que "mas qual !" fosse uma expressão conhecida por todos, por isso não expliquei.

Comment: @ANeves e Centauros acho que é mesmo quá...

Comment: @JorgeB.  Sim, na música é "quá", palavra que não existe em português.  Por isso eu escrevei **"acredito que"** ao invés de **"tenho certeza que"**.

Comment: Ah, então significa "mas qual (rei)!", é? Assim faria sentido.

Comment: Em Portugal diríamos "mas o quê!" ou "(mas) qual quê!" mais ou menos com o mesmo significado. Quando escreves "qual o que!" faltará lá o "^"?

Comment: @Jacinto   Obrigado, tens razão.  Foi "um lápis" como diria Mrs Malaprop.

Comment: "Quê" e "que" são homófonos no Brasil? Facilita os lápis...

Comment: @Centaurus Eu não conhecia o *mas qual!*, mas o escritor português Júlio Dinis (1839-71) conhecia: «enfim... se fosse um homem capaz... mas qual!... algum menino bonito, algum peralvilhito de Lisboa» ([Os Fidalgos da Casa Mourisca](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/search-dp4.html?searchphrase=all&searchword=fidalgos+da+casa+mourisca) ; download livre).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the music. But probably its an abreviation of "mas qual". "Mas qual" translated to english is something like "But which?".

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you explained how that meaning fits with the story told by the other verses.

Comment: I don't know the song. Not music.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que vale um comentário sobre a pronúncia.

Em algumas variantes regionais e sociais do português brasileiro, o "l" final não é realizado. "Quá" é uma variante de "qual" -- com função de interjeição, como já bem explicado por outros comentaristas.

Outros exemplos dessa pronúncia.
 - aluguel > alugé
 - Natal > Natá
 - arraial > arraiá
 - mel > mé
 - mal e mal > mal-e-má

Para quem não é falante nativo, vale notar que essas realizações fonéticas em geral são socialmente estigmatizadas como folclóricas ou iletradas.

A título de curiosidade: as línguas do grupo banto, trazidas pelos povos escravizados da África, deixaram marcas profundas não apenas no léxico corrente da língua materna da maioria dos brasileiros, mas também na sua morfossintaxe e, hoje se sabe, na pronúncia. Eu não ficaria surpreso se  essa queda do "l" fosse mais uma contribuição dos idiomas bantos no português do Brasil.

Answer (score 1):

Em uma determinada região da Bahia nós usamos "quá" pra expressar descrença/dúvida ou desilusão.

exemplo: "quá, você acredita nisso?"

ou quando alguém pergunta: -"você acha que Arthur vai cumprir o prometido?"

você pode responder: -"quá",    pra expressar que você duvida muito que isso aconteça.

Um outro uso que do "quá" por lá é com o sentido de "o quê",

ex.: -"você vai assistir ao filme ou quá?", que seria o equivalente a

- "você vai assistir ao filme ou o quê?

Não sei ao certo a origem, mas o segundo exemplo de uso do 'quá' poderia sim ser algo derivado do 'quoi' do francês. Faz algum sentido, mas não posso afirmar que seja realmente isso.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma :)

Answer (score 1):

"Mas quá despertei"
Expressão de decepção, melancolia.
Na década de 70, quando esta música fez sucesso, na escola fizemos a análise sintática de sua letra e concluímos, salvo algum esquecimento pelo tempo decorrido, que a expressão denotaria a "desilusão e surpresa pelo despertar para a vida adulta (adolescência) e pelo fim da infância inocente".

Comment: Muito boa explicação.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que vem do francês "Quoi", que significa "o quê" e se pronuncia /qwa/ 'qüá'. Lembrando que os franceses tiveram forte presença no Rio de Janeiro e no Nordeste (mais precisamente entre Paraíba e Pará), e posteriormente no movimento imigratório comandado por D. João VI.